# name 'Node' is not defined

Tags: ros2, webots

when we launched the following example in the Webots-ros2 tutorial, we got the following error, could you help us to get rid of that problem, thanks.

The example link: [Setting up a robot simulation (Advanced)](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Advanced.html)

**ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/ros2_ws/src$** `ros2 launch my_package robot_launch.py`

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ntukenmez3/.ros/log/2023-09-07-17-39-57-599365-ae-icps-407120-1653965
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
WARNING: No valid Webots directory specified in `ROS2_WEBOTS_HOME` and `WEBOTS_HOME`, fallback to default installation folder /usr/local/webots.
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: name 'Node' is not defined
```

---

**my_robot_driver.py:**

```
import rclpy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

HALF_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_WHEELS = 0.045
WHEEL_RADIUS = 0.025

class MyRobotDriver:
    def init(self, webots_node, properties):
        self.__robot = webots_node.robot

        self.__left_motor = self.__robot.getDevice('left wheel motor')
        self.__right_motor = self.__robot.getDevice('right wheel motor')

        self.__left_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        self.__left_motor.setVelocity(0)

        self.__right_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        self.__right_motor.setVelocity(0)

        self.__target_twist = Twist()

        rclpy.init(args=None)
        self.__node = rclpy.create_node('my_robot_driver')
        self.__node.create_subscription(Twist, 'cmd_vel', self.__cmd_vel_callback, 1)

    def __cmd_vel_callback(self, twist):
        self.__target_twist = twist

    def step(self):
        rclpy.spin_once(self.__node, timeout_sec=0)

        forward_speed = self.__target_twist.linear.x
        angular_speed = self.__target_twist.angular.z

        command_motor_left = (forward_speed - angular_speed * HALF_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_WHEELS) / WHEEL_RADIUS
        command_motor_right = (forward_speed + angular_speed * HALF_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_WHEELS) / WHEEL_RADIUS

        self.__left_motor.setVelocity(command_motor_left)
        self.__right_motor.setVelocity(command_motor_right)
```

**obstacle_avoider.py:**

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Range
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist


MAX_RANGE = 0.15


class ObstacleAvoider(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('obstacle_avoider')

        self.__publisher = self.create_publisher(Twist, 'cmd_vel', 1)

        self.create_subscription(Range, 'left_sensor', self.__left_sensor_callback, 1)
        self.create_subscription(Range, 'right_sensor', self.__right_sensor_callback, 1)

    def __left_sensor_callback(self, message):
        self.__left_sensor_value = message.range

    def __right_sensor_callback(self, message):
        self.__right_sensor_value = message.range

        command_message = Twist()

        command_message.linear.x = 0.1

        if self.__left_sensor_value < 0.9 * MAX_RANGE or self.__right_sensor_value < 0.9 * MAX_RANGE:
            command_message.angular.z = -2.0

        self.__publisher.publish(command_message)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    avoider = ObstacleAvoider()
    rclpy.spin(avoider)
    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    avoider.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**my_robot.urdf:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="My robot">
    <webots>
        <device reference="ds0" type="DistanceSensor">
            <ros>
                <topicName>/left_sensor</topicName>
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            </ros>
        </device>
        <device reference="ds1" type="DistanceSensor">
            <ros>
                <topicName>/right_sensor</topicName>
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            </ros>
        </device>
        <plugin type="my_package.my_robot_driver.MyRobotDriver" />
    </webots>
</robot>
```

**robot_launch.py:**

```
import os
import launch
from launch import LaunchDescription
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from webots_ros2_driver.webots_launcher import WebotsLauncher
from webots_ros2_driver.webots_controller import WebotsController


def generate_launch_description():
    package_dir = get_package_share_directory('my_package')
    robot_description_path = os.path.join(package_dir, 'resource', 'my_robot.urdf')

    webots = WebotsLauncher(
        world=os.path.join(package_dir, 'worlds', 'my_world.wbt')
    )

    my_robot_driver = WebotsController(
        robot_name='my_robot',
        parameters=[
            {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
        ]
    )

    obstacle_avoider = Node(
        package='my_package',
        executable='obstacle_avoider',
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        webots,
        my_robot_driver,
        obstacle_avoider,
        launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=launch.event_handlers.OnProcessExit(
                target_action=webots,
                on_exit=[launch.actions.EmitEvent(event=launch.events.Shutdown())],
            )
        )
    ])
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'my_package'
data_files = []
data_files.append(('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages', ['resource/' + package_name]))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name + '/launch', ['launch/robot_launch.py']))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name + '/worlds', ['worlds/my_world.wbt']))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name + '/resource', ['resource/my_robot.urdf']))
data_files.append(('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']))
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=data_files,
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='user',
    maintainer_email='user.name@mail.com',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_robot_driver = my_package.my_robot_driver:main',
            'obstacle_avoider = my_package.obstacle_avoider:main'
    ],
    },
)
```

Comment: We have several files, are there any options to upload here, thanks.

Comment: I'll edit the question now, thanks.

Comment: The related code was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

in the `launch.py` file: `from launch_ros.actions import Node`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tutorial and without seeing your code I would say you're missing the `Node` definition, which is invoked with `from rclpy.node import Node` ([as per the tutorial you mention](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Advanced.html)), but please add your code nonetheless.

Comment: I added the code, could you check it, if possible.

Comment: It seems you're missing the line `from rclpy.node import Node` in your `robot_launch.py`, as it is used in the line where you define the obstacle_avoider.

Comment: I used `rom launch_ros.actions import Node` in the `robot_launch.py`. It works now. Is it same with your solution? How did you figure out this problem before, I mean How did you realize this is the problem, thanks.

Comment: I guess it's not exactly the same solution, as `from launch_ros.actions import Node` is the appropriate import for launch files. but it was still about imports, so there are similarities. In the future I would really suggest you follow the error messages first, before posting a question, as the line `name 'Node' is not defined` clearly states you're not defining `Node`. I just used the simple tools of `Ctrl + F` to find where the word `Node` is located and compared it with your posted code. I can edit my answer so you can accept it or you can write a new answer and accept it.

Comment: I'll try your solution.

Comment: Your solution did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Those instructions say to run the launch file from the ROS workspace and you're running it from the SCR folder. Try it exactly as the instruction call for. This might not correct your issue but you should always start by checking you're following the instructions.

Comment: Two things 1. *"the SCR folde..."* you mean the `src` folder?. 2. I am sorry but you can invoke ROS commands from anywhere.

Comment: I could not get it this answer.